# react native text horizontal cutting, need full text in one line how to do that?

Tags: react-native

react-native version: "0.62.0", I tried this code
ui coming like this:
[image]
            
              
       
       React Native

```
          </View>
          <View style={{flex:8}}>
            <View style={{padding: 20, height: 200, backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
              <Text style={fonts.bold}>View 1</Text>
            </View>

            <View style={{padding: 20, height: 200, backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
              <Text style={fonts.bold}>View 1</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{padding: 20, height: 200, backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}>
              <Text>View 1</Text>
            </View>

            <View style={{padding: 20, height: 200, backgroundColor: 'green'}}>
              <Text>View 1</Text>
            </View>
          </View>

        </View>
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

give Text width  greater than space occupied by characters with some padding

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you did not provide the code for intended green view. The green view in your code is different. It is under yellow view.

Tip: For intended view try to remove height and width properties.

Answer (score 0):

Created a sample according to your problem

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.wrapperStyle}>
                <View style={styles.leftStyle}>
                    <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Trending</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.rightStyle}>
                    <Text>View 1</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.wrapperStyle}>
                <View style={[styles.leftStyle, { backgroundColor: 'green' }]}>
                    <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Top_games</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={[styles.rightStyle, { backgroundColor: 'yellow' }]}>
                    <Text>View 2</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        paddingTop: 20,
    },
    wrapperStyle: {
        height: 200,
        flexDirection: 'row'
    },
    leftStyle: {
        flex: 2,
        backgroundColor: 'gray',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    rightStyle: {
        flex: 8,
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    textStyle: {
        transform: [{ rotate: '-90deg' }]
    }
});
```

Somtetimes you have to change `flex` value according to your requirements.

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Comment: yes it helps, but left vertical bar need to be separate scroll as you it going to work like tab system. so it will by tabs
right content will be display on the basis of left side button press.

Left side column need seprate list of items

Comment: one more Question , leftStyle: {
      flex: 1,
       }
i need size flex 1, but text are not coming in 1 line

Comment: when text becomes wider than your left view it will automatically assign to a new line. try to add ```numberOfLines={1}``` or change the width of your left view. also, you can try an external library ```react-native-vertical-text```